# bundler cannot install commonmarker

Tags: jekyll, bundler, github-pages

I'm trying to [set up a GitHub Pages repo](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll). Steps I've followed:

#### Install bundler

```
$ gem install bundler
```

```
Fetching: bundler-2.0.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-2.0.2
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.0.2
Installing ri documentation for bundler-2.0.2
Done installing documentation for bundler after 27 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Good.

#### Create Gemfile specifying Jekyll at current GH version (3.8.5)

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "jekyll", "3.8.5"
```

#### Run bundle install

```
$ bundle install
```

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching public_suffix 4.0.1
Installing public_suffix 4.0.1
Fetching addressable 2.7.0
Installing addressable 2.7.0
Using bundler 2.0.2
Fetching colorator 1.1.0
Installing colorator 1.1.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
Fetching eventmachine 1.2.7 (x64-mingw32)
Installing eventmachine 1.2.7 (x64-mingw32)
Fetching http_parser.rb 0.6.0
Installing http_parser.rb 0.6.0 with native extensions
Fetching em-websocket 0.5.1
Installing em-websocket 0.5.1
Fetching ffi 1.11.2 (x64-mingw32)
Installing ffi 1.11.2 (x64-mingw32)
Fetching forwardable-extended 2.6.0
Installing forwardable-extended 2.6.0
Using i18n 0.9.5
Fetching rb-fsevent 0.10.3
Installing rb-fsevent 0.10.3
Fetching rb-inotify 0.10.0
Installing rb-inotify 0.10.0
Fetching sass-listen 4.0.0
Installing sass-listen 4.0.0
Fetching sass 3.7.4
Installing sass 3.7.4
Fetching jekyll-sass-converter 1.5.2
Installing jekyll-sass-converter 1.5.2
Fetching listen 3.2.0
Installing listen 3.2.0
Fetching jekyll-watch 2.2.1
Installing jekyll-watch 2.2.1
Fetching kramdown 1.17.0
Installing kramdown 1.17.0
Fetching liquid 4.0.3
Installing liquid 4.0.3
Fetching mercenary 0.3.6
Installing mercenary 0.3.6
Fetching pathutil 0.16.2
Installing pathutil 0.16.2
Fetching rouge 3.13.0
Installing rouge 3.13.0
Fetching safe_yaml 1.0.5
Installing safe_yaml 1.0.5
Fetching jekyll 3.8.5
Installing jekyll 3.8.5
Bundle complete! 1 Gemfile dependency, 25 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
Post-install message from sass:

Ruby Sass has reached end-of-life and should no longer be used.

* If you use Sass as a command-line tool, we recommend using Dart Sass, the new
  primary implementation: https://sass-lang.com/install

* If you use Sass as a plug-in for a Ruby web framework, we recommend using the
  sassc gem: https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby#readme

* For more details, please refer to the Sass blog:
  https://sass-lang.com/blog/posts/7828841
```

Some warnings about obsolete packages, but good.

#### Create new site (Guide step 7)

```
$ bundler exec jekyll new .
```

*Rewrites Gemfile to*

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

# Hello! This is where you manage which Jekyll version is used to run.
# When you want to use a different version, change it below, save the
# file and run `bundle install`. Run Jekyll with `bundle exec`, like so:
#
#     bundle exec jekyll serve
#
# This will help ensure the proper Jekyll version is running.
# Happy Jekylling!
gem "jekyll", "~> 3.8.5"

# This is the default theme for new Jekyll sites. You may change this to anything you like.
gem "minima", "~> 2.0"

# If you want to use GitHub Pages, remove the "gem "jekyll"" above and
# uncomment the line below. To upgrade, run `bundle update github-pages`.
# gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins

# If you have any plugins, put them here!
group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-feed", "~> 0.6"
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

# Performance-booster for watching directories on Windows
gem "wdm", "~> 0.1.0" if Gem.win_platform?
```

and outputs:

```
Running bundle install in C:/Projects/coding-for-smarties...
  Bundler: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in `block in verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!': Could not find gem 'minima (~> 2.0) x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
  Bundler: from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:255:in `each'
  Bundler: from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:255:in `verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!'
  Bundler: from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:49:in `start'
  Bundler: from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:22:in `resolve'
  Bundler: from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:258:in `resolve'
  Bundler: from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:170:in `specs'
  Bundler: from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:237:in `specs_for'
  Bundler: from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:226:in `requested_specs'
  Bundler: from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:108:in `block in definition_method'
  Bundler: from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
  Bundler: from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
  Bundler: from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
  Bundler: from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  Bundler: from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

***ERROR*** Could not find gem 'minima (~> 2.0) x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.

Probably not a problem because I want a different theme anyway.  So I update it, and I also make the changes suggested in Guide steps 8 & 9.

#### Try install again

```
$ bundle install
```

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies......................
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
Using i18n 0.9.5
Fetching minitest 5.13.0
Installing minitest 5.13.0
Fetching thread_safe 0.3.6
Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
Fetching tzinfo 1.2.5
Installing tzinfo 1.2.5
Fetching activesupport 4.2.10
Installing activesupport 4.2.10
Fetching public_suffix 2.0.5 (was 4.0.1)
Installing public_suffix 2.0.5 (was 4.0.1)
Using addressable 2.7.0
Using bundler 2.0.2
Fetching coffee-script-source 1.11.1
Installing coffee-script-source 1.11.1
Fetching execjs 2.7.0
Installing execjs 2.7.0
Fetching coffee-script 2.4.1
Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
Using colorator 1.1.0
Fetching ruby-enum 0.7.2
Installing ruby-enum 0.7.2
Fetching commonmarker 0.17.13
Installing commonmarker 0.17.13 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/commonmarker-0.17.13/ext/commonmarker
C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20191114-10956-3hyma7.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory:
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/commonmarker-0.17.13/ext/commonmarker
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory:
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/commonmarker-0.17.13/ext/commonmarker
make "DESTDIR="
generating commonmarker-x64-mingw32.def
compiling arena.c
compiling autolink.c
compiling blocks.c
compiling buffer.c
compiling cmark.c
compiling cmark_ctype.c
compiling commonmark.c
compiling commonmarker.c
In file included from C:/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from commonmarker.h:9,
                 from commonmarker.c:1:
C:/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:631:1: warning: 'const' attribute
on function returning 'void' [-Wattributes]
  631 | CONSTFUNC(void rb_secure_update(VALUE));
      | ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2012,
                 from C:/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from commonmarker.h:9,
                 from commonmarker.c:1:
C:/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/intern.h:257:1: warning: 'const' attribute
on function returning 'void' [-Wattributes]
  257 | CONSTFUNC(void rb_error_untrusted(VALUE));
      | ^~~~~~~~~
C:/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/intern.h:259:1: warning: 'const' attribute
on function returning 'void' [-Wattributes]
  259 | CONSTFUNC(void rb_check_trusted(VALUE));
      | ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from houdini.h:9,
                 from commonmarker.c:3:
config.h:8: warning: "HAVE_STDBOOL_H" redefined
    8 | #define HAVE_STDBOOL_H
      |
In file included from C:/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:24,
                 from C:/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from commonmarker.h:9,
                 from commonmarker.c:1:
C:/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0/x64-mingw32/ruby/config.h:30: note: this is the
location of the previous definition
   30 | #define HAVE_STDBOOL_H 1
      |
compiling core-extensions.c
compiling ext_scanners.c
compiling footnotes.c
compiling houdini_href_e.c
compiling houdini_html_e.c
compiling houdini_html_u.c
compiling html.c
compiling inlines.c
compiling iterator.c
compiling latex.c
compiling linked_list.c
compiling man.c
compiling map.c
compiling node.c
compiling plaintext.c
compiling plugin.c
compiling references.c
compiling registry.c
compiling render.c
compiling scanners.c
compiling strikethrough.c
compiling syntax_extension.c
compiling table.c
compiling tagfilter.c
compiling utf8.c
compiling xml.c
linking shared-object commonmarker/commonmarker.so
C:/Ruby24-x64/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
strikethrough.o:strikethrough.c:(.text+0x2ba): undefined reference to
`__memset_chk'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:259: commonmarker.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/commonmarker-0.17.13 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.4.0/commonmarker-0.17.13/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing commonmarker (0.17.13), and Bundler
cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install commonmarker -v '0.17.13' --source
'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  github-pages was resolved to 187, which depends on
    jekyll-commonmark-ghpages was resolved to 0.1.5, which depends on
      jekyll-commonmark was resolved to 1.3.1, which depends on
        commonmarker
```

***ERROR*** An error occurred while installing commonmarker (0.17.13), and Bundler cannot continue.

And I can't get past this.  The best I can do is remove all my gem packages and restart, which just leads me back here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative would be to "[use Jekyll in Windows with Docker](https://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/Running-Jekyll-in-Windows-using-Docker/)" (from [James Sturtevant](https://github.com/jsturtevant))

That would take advantage of the Docker image [`jekyll/jekyll`](https://hub.docker.com/r/jekyll/jekyll/) (see [its README](https://github.com/envygeeks/jekyll-docker/blob/master/README.md)).

```
export JEKYLL_VERSION=3.8
docker run --rm \
  --volume="$PWD:/srv/jekyll" \
  -it jekyll/jekyll:$JEKYLL_VERSION \
  jekyll build
```

And you don't have to install ruby or wrestle with missing dependencies.

Comment: I should learn to read.  I spent 3 hours trying to build a dockerfile starting from ubuntu.  In the end, the single command in the blog post did it.